# Source for photographs of sample checks

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm working on an OCR functionality around checks, specifically around a user taking a photograph of a check, and I'm looking to acquire a data set to quantify the success of our various features.

Does anyone know of such a set already in existence that meets these requirements?

Comment: Although it may not be an exact match due to content, as you're looking for handwriting samples, the [USPS takes pictures of envelopes](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052970204394804577012122145910692) .... but I don't know if it qualifies as PII, and exempt from FOIA requests.  (it's also come out since then that they were [imaging *all* envelopes](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/report-postal-service-uses-spying-programs-similar-to-nsa//), not just the hard-to-read ones.)

Comment: This is an interesting source. I'm specifically looking at feature detection and isolation around MICR encoding on checks, so PCA isn't really a part of the problem before me. I'll keep this in mind though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Here is a non-direct path (assuming you are using Windows).

**TL;DR** print hard copies with check font, scan/photograph them, use OCR.

I used Python to write the few [MICR characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition#Unicode) in Unicode. I use the utf-16-le (little endian) encoding with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16).

```
import codecs
with open('micr.txt','wb') as output:
    output.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16)
    for ichar in xrange(9280,9280+11):
        line = ( u'1'+unichr(ichar)+u'\n').encode('utf-16')
        output.write(line)
    output.write( (u'0123456789'+u'\n').encode('utf-16') )
```

The output looks like this (I suggest using Notepad++ or another high-level text editor). It's required to have some character before each of the non-numeric MICR unicode characters, I just chose '1' for simplicity:

```
1⑀ 
1⑁ 
1⑂
1⑃
1⑄
1⑅ 
1⑆
1⑇
1⑈
1⑉
1⑊
0123456789
```

These are all the possible unicode characters for MICR. Of course, the font is wrong. (A simpler method would be to copy paste from [here](http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2b2440))

The MICR font costs money, unfortunately, but there is an open version: [GnuMICR](http://www.sandeen.net/GnuMICR/). You can download the font directly here: [GnuMICR.ttf](http://www.sandeen.net/GnuMICR/download/GnuMICR-0.30/GnuMICR.ttf). To install, just double click and then restart and running programs where you want to use it.

I then took my output text from above, and pasted it into LibreOffice Writer (other MS Word-like programs will work, too). Highlight all the text and change the font to **GnuMICR**. I've shared the LibreOffice Writer .ODT file [here](https://github.com/philshem/philshem.github.io/raw/master/data/unicode_micr.odt) (you must have the GnuMICR font already installed).

The screenshot below shows what my screen looks like.

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice Writer with the GnuMICR font and unicode characters]

From here, you can use the Python code or lots of copy/paste to generate unlimited routing and account numbers. *Let me know if you want a python snippet to generate fake routing/account numbers.*

To really test the OCR, generate your own [MICR documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) by physically printing your digital "checks" and then scan/photograph (re-digitize) them. Between printing and scanning you can have some fun by folding, spilling coffee, etc.

You can also digitally damage the images, for example, by using [Python Imagine Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and methods such as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15145046/2327328).

Comment: What a great answer! I like this as a concept a lot. I think that deploying this in conjunction with some artificial noising and exposure confluence could give us a really strong data set.

Comment: Glad you like it. I realized half-way that you can skip the coding and just copy-paste.

Comment: Please consider sharing this data set once you've created it.